# New Project in JBoss-AS environment - which one?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss

I got a book about JPA and I want to follow some of the contained tutorials. I want to use JSF, JPA and some EJBs. I got some difficulties, which application server and project type to choose? Currently I am using Eclipse Juno and Windows 7, I installed JBoss-AS 7.1. I was told that JBoss needs the Maven plugin as well. I installed it. I could pick tons of projects which seems suitable like EJB, JSF, JPA, ant, maven ...

My first guess was to go for a Dynamic Web Project - is this correct? I was trying some tutorials with Tomcat before, so I am new to application servers.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to have significant JPA layer, use separate project for that (JPA project), otherwise create EJB project, where you would keep your EJBs and JPA entities. In this project you will develop your application's bussiness layer.

Then create Dynamic Web Project, add your EJB project as a dependency and create web interface using JSF.

The last step is to create EAR Project (Enterprise application project) and add to it your EJB project and Dynamic Web project. As a product you will get application deployable on the application server.

Note that you can also use new local EJBs (if you are targeting Java EE 6), that can be deployed in the WAR application. In that case you don't need EAR.

Comment: Thanks Piotr, I was afraid of such an answer :-). There are so many options, that it is hard to pick the right one to start. If I like to create a small webapp, let's say 10 entity classes, 3 views and 3 controllers, which JEE architecture makes sense. I am just trying to make the next step after deploying to a tomcat instance. I read about using a DAO-Layer, a service layer or not?! Maybe you or anyone else knows a small tutorial, which will get me startet with your preferred kind of project structure. Thanks in advance!